# Getting parent category hierarchy as objects from category template

Tags: categories

What is the best way to get the hierarchy of parent **category objects** from the `category.php` template, when there is no post as such.

The function [`get_category_parents()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents) returns a string not the objects.

The function [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) seems to be intended for pages where there is a post because the `type` argument can take either `post` or `link`.

Is there any other function I am missing? I would need something that behaves exactly like `get_category_parents()` but I need the category objects not just a string of all of the names.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a built in function that does what you are asking but it is not that hard to cook up. In fact, you are pretty close. `get_categories` is correct but it needs the `child_of` argument, which means finding the topmost parent via `get_ancestors`. `child_of` will only return children, not the specified parent, so that parent has to be inserted into the results manually.

```
var_dump(get_category_parents(5)); // reference
$anc = get_ancestors(5,'category');
$parent = array_pop($anc);
$hier[] = get_category($parent);
$args = array(
  'child_of' => $parent,
); 
array_push($hier,get_categories($args));
var_dump($hier);
```

Comment: Thanks. What I did instead is that I used the `parent` property of the current category. If I call `get_category($current_category->parent)` recursively until I find one which has `parent = 0`, I suppose I will get all the hierarchy. Seems to be working unless there is a catch somewhere.

Comment: @jbx: you might compare the execution time of your code to this code. I honestly don't know which will be quicker.

Comment: WHat you describe, by the way, sounds a lot like [what `get_ancestors` already does](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L3392)